# Type I error in Negative Binomial GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

In the following R code, the expected type I error should be 0.05 (I think), but it is consistently greater than 0.05. I want to know why.

```
library(MASS)    
nsim <- 1000
alpha <- 0.05
out <- rep(NA,nsim)
for(i in 1:nsim){
  x <- runif(20,0,10)
  y <- rnbinom(20,mu=3,size=1.285714)
  out[i] <- summary(glm.nb(y~x))$coefficients[2,4]
}
mean(out<alpha)
```

Comment: Small sample size? When I use a sample size of `2000` the type 1 error rate is `.047` - which is pretty close I would say for 1000 simulations. It appears to me that those coefficients for `glm` are Wald tests - which will only asymptotically give the correct type 1 errors.

Comment: I still get >0.05 all the time even if nsim <- 2000. set.seed(1001) will give 0.0745, set.seed(1002) will give 0.078, set.seed(1003) will give 0.066, set.seed(1004) will give 0.081, and set.seed(1005) will give 0.066. Increasing sample size from 20 to 50 does not solve the problem...

Comment: No not the number of simulations, the size of each sample for each run. So set `x <- runif(2000,0,10)` and `y <- rnbinom(2000,mu=3,size=1.285714)`.

Comment: Actually it is already perfectly working with a samples size of 100 instead of 20. 2000 is not even necessary.

Comment: Oh, it has to be that large...